# General prohibition of cutting down fruit trees?

Tags: halacha, trees

Does the [restriction on cutting down fruit trees](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/07/31/nyregion/for-some-orthodox-jews-a-rule-against-chopping-down-fruit-trees.html?_r=3&smid=fb-share) apply generally outside of Israel? For some reason I thought it was only:
1. Within Israel
2. When conquering land of an enemy (outside of Israel, but an extraordinary case).

Was I mistaken?

Comment: You are remembering the context of the original pasuk http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0520.htm#19 but I believe the law is generalized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/961313/jewish/Cutting-Down-Fruit-Trees.htm

http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5763/shavous.html

It applies all over.

Comment: The second article talks about the holiday of "Shevuos" `:-)`